# Identifying Design Pattern of this code

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Can anyone help me to identify which design pattern or patterns are used in the following code snippet. It looks little like half **strategy pattern** but with **generics**. It is a just sample code and was not taken from an actual code base or something.

The reason why I am saying it looks like a strategy pattern is that it seems it is shifting behavioral logic using generics in controllers such as `DogController<DogRepository>`. It could have been like `animalController.Repository = new DogRepository()`.

```
void Main()
{
    var animalController = new DogController();
    animalController.PrintName();
}

abstract class AnimalControllerBase<TRepository> where TRepository : IAnimalRepository
{
    protected abstract TRepository AnimalRepository {get;}

    public void PrintName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AnimalRepository.Get());
    }
}

class DogController : AnimalControllerBase<DogRepository>
{
    protected override DogRepository AnimalRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return new DogRepository();
        }
    }
}

class CatController : AnimalControllerBase<CatRepository>
{
    protected override CatRepository AnimalRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return new CatRepository();
        }
    }
}

interface IAnimalRepository
{
    string Get();
}

class DogRepository : IAnimalRepository
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello, I am Steve the dog..";
    }
}

class CatRepository : IAnimalRepository
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello, I am Michael the cat..";
    }
}
```

Comment: looks a lot like namedropping, especially the "repository" part. If any design pattern is in place, here is a little factory method. Repository and Controller can be completely ignored!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it is the [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern in disguise. `AnimalControllerBase` defines the interface of the Factory Method pattern i.e. `protected abstract TRepository AnimalRepository {get;}` and every subclass or concrete Factory Method implementation provides the actual creational code:

```
// disguise of a concrete Factory Method implementation that creates instances of 
// DogRepository and every time you call get you get a new instance
class DogController : AnimalControllerBase<DogRepository>
{
   protected override DogRepository AnimalRepository
   {
       get
       {
           return new DogRepository();
       }
   }
}
```

Why not Strategy? the OO structure is similar but conceptually very different. Strategy "parameterizes" behavior whereas here you have instance creation parametrization. Actually most design patterns boil down to a few OO structures e.g. Proxy is exactly the same OO structure as Decorator but conceptually they are very different.

Comment: Would you elaborate your answer little bit more. In which code section did you see the factory pattern and how does it resembles factory method pattern?